# Kibana Watcher showing incorrect results

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, alert

I've configured a simple Kibana Watcher, sending an email if a number of logged errors over the index exceeds 100 per hour.

But, I've noticed that the number of the errors it returns doesn't match the number of the errors returned in the Discover pane with the filter "level:ERROR".

Has anyone experienced something like this?

*Discover*:
level:ERROR, range: last hour

*Watcher*:

````
  "trigger": {
    "schedule": {
      "interval": "1h"
    }
  },
  "input": {
    "search": {
      "request": {
        "search_type": "query_then_fetch",
        "indices": [
          "myindex-*"
        ],
        "rest_total_hits_as_int": true,
        "body": {
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "query_string": {
                    "query": "ERROR"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "range": {
                    "@timestamp": {
                      "gte": "now-1h"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "_source": [
            "level"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "condition": {
    "compare": {
      "ctx.payload.hits.total": {
        "gte": 100
      }
    }
  },
  "actions": {
    "email_action": {
      "email": {
        "profile": "standard",
        "to": [
          "email@email.test"
        ],
        "subject": "Kibana Watcher: Errors count over threshold (hourly)",
        "body": {
          "text": "Encountered {{ctx.payload.hits.total}} log errors in the last hour"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}```
````

Comment: Did you compare the query sent by Kibana in the Discover view with the one you're using in your Watcher definition?

Comment: Queries are actually quite different, and Watcher is using query_string in "must" and Discover in "should". If I try changing Watcher to use Discover query, it returns "ctx.payload.hits.total": 10000, while the count in Discover is 17